# How to fix timeout/null reply with Axon DistributedCommandBus (Spring Cloud & Eureka)

Tags: java, spring-cloud, axon

I am working on Axon DistributedCommandBus with spring cloud and eureka. (2 nodes) When the command is send, it is dispatched to another node and command is handled on another node. But it is getting timeout in the invoker node. Noticed the same behaviour on success and exception cases.

When I debug (SpringHttpCommandBusConnector), the response is received and it is null (replyMessage is null).

```java
SpringHttpReplyMessage<R> replyMessage = this.<C, R>sendRemotely(destination, commandMessage, EXPECT_REPLY).getBody();
if (replyMessage != null) {
    callback.onResult(commandMessage, replyMessage.getCommandResultMessage(serializer));
}
```

Why the replymessage is null here. And if the replymessage is null, the callback is not updated and it is waiting indefinitely.

Can someone help me to figure out the issue and help me to fix this.

Thanks

EDIT:
1. I am using DisruptorCommandBus as localSegment
2. Response is received with status 200 and null body

Comment: Response is received with status 200 and body is null

Comment: Just to rule some things out, have you tried using a different local segment then the `DisruptorCommandBus`? So, does it work with for example the `SimpleCommandBus`? And secondly, have you verified your command is being received on the other node?

Comment: @Steven  I tried with SimpleCommandBus as localSegment, the behaviour is same. At the same time, The request is processed on another node only the response from that node is received as NULL.

Comment: Do you by any chance see the following in your logs:
`Could not serialize command reply [{insert-command-result-message}]. Sending back NULL.`

That would opt for a serialization error, I think.
Regardless, if you see that in your logs, it would be valuable to share the stack trace of the exception attached to it.